# State of a custom widget broken in ListView.build after adding new data

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-state

I have a ListView.builder. It renders a custom widget named "messageBubble". Inside the messageBubble, there is a state value for radio button list. When an option selected, callback method triggered and the method adds a new data item for ListView.builder.

The problem is when rendered the new item, the state value in the messageBuble is broken. Before the item, an option was selected, after rendered the new item selection is gone.

Here is the ListView.builder:

```
Widget buildListMessage() {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: messageProvider.getMessageBySession(activeSessionID),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData && (snapshot.data?.docs.length ?? 0) > 0) {
          print('snapshot.data?.docs.length: ${snapshot.data?.docs.length}');
          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            reverse: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildMessageBubble(context,
                snapshot.data?.docs[index], index, snapshot.data?.docs.length),
            itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
          );
        } else {
          return const Center(
            child: TypingIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

In the messageMessable widget, the method named "onRadioButtonChanged" create a new data. "selectedRadioValue" is a state and the onRadioButtonChanged set its value.

If I don't create the new data, everything works properly.

```
 void onRadioButtonChanged(int selectedValue) {
    setState(() {
      selectedRadioValue = selectedValue;
    });
    //CREATING NEW DATA
  }

Widget buildRadioButtons() {
    return Column(
      children: buildRadioButtonItems(),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> buildRadioButtonItems() {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    for (dynamic item in widget.message.botResponseData) {
      KeyValueModel keyValueModel = KeyValueModel.fromJson(item);

      widgets.add(
        buildCustomRadioListTile(keyValueModel.text, keyValueModel.index),
      );
    }
    return widgets;
  }

  Widget buildCustomRadioListTile(String text, int value) {
    return CustomRadioListTile<int>(
      value: value,
      groupValue: selectedRadioValue,
      title: Text(text),
      onChanged: (value) {
        onRadioButtonChanged(value!);
      },
    );
  }
```

In the result, I need to list a data. Inside the list, a data item can have a radio button group. User can select an option and according to selected option, a new data will be created.

Since I have to create new data once user selects an option on radio button list, I could not figure out what to do.

Comment: maybe creating a variable for `stream: messageProvider.getMessageBySession(activeSessionID)`,try [this video](https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg?si=w1wPvjjwyTvnIDdH)

Comment: I defined key values for the builder and messageBubble and it is working now.

return ListView.builder(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildMessageBubble(
      ..,
      key: UniqueKey(),
   ),
);